# DropDownList selected value on click ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have this ddl:

```
        <asp:DropDownList  ID="ddl" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">My Images</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">My Documents</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to show images below that dropdownlist only when a user click on "My Images"

I know how to open an alert when a user click on one of the options, but I dont know how to show things in the same page.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you could do that with javascript: create a function that responds to an onchange event and then if option selected is 2, then put images in a div and show-hide that div

Comment: or use ASP.NET servcer-side code and put images in a panel and change visibility of that panel

Comment: I did it and now I have another question..
I have a MySql database, and I want to show things from the database, there is anyway to retrieve information from the database in JavaScript?

Comment: you could build Web API that pulls data from the database from javascrip

Answer (score 0):

Put your images inside a div:

```
<div id="myImages" class="ShowHide">
  your images here
</div>
```

add javascript to the server-side:

```
ddl.Attributes["onchange"] = "ddl_onchange()";
```

add css class:

```
<style>
   .ShowHide {
       display: none;
    }

</style>
```

and below is the javascript code that will show or hide images div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ddl_onchange(){
        var el = document.getElementById("ddl");
        var panel = document.getELementById("myImages");
        if (el.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "2")
             panel.style.display ="block";
        else
            panel.style.display ="none";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: its now working for me..

I put this code in cs file

  ddl.Attributes["onchange"] = "ddl_onchange()";

and its not showing the image when I click on the options

Comment: what happens if you put the following line right before if statement in your javascript? `alert(el.options[e.selectedIndex].value);`